# Difference between Adjectives

Tags: adjectives, attributive-nouns

What is the difference in meaning between *education* and *educational* in the following examples?

*Education center* and
*Educational center*

Answer (score 1):

*Education* as an adjective means *pertaining to, or used for, education*.

*Educational* is more often used to mean *providing information or a learning opportunity* (an educational book or game).

So I consider *Education center* a better choice.